# Users in a Queue will get Leads alternately assigned

Tags: queue, assignment-rules

I have added two users in Queue and added that to Lead Assignment rules. Based on the criteria the Leads were assigning to that Queue. But my higher authorities were asking that Leads should assign alternately to the 2 users in Queue, that means 1st Lead will go to 1st person in queue and the 2nd one to 2nd person in queue. Is that Possible, If so Please explain.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I believe that you are looking for Round Robin Lead Assignment.

Please visit the following link-
[Create a Round Robin Lead Assignment Rule](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.essentials_round_robin_lead_assignment.htm&type=5)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your help,

Comment: I tried it but we have different countries here and based on countries it needs to be assigned alternately